# Crystal reports intergration with Visual Studio 17

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I am very new to ASP.NET and this is my very first project. I am trying to run a already developed project which uses Crystal reports 13. I downloaded crystal reports 13 but when i try to run the application it fails.

Error is as follows:
[image]

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have installed the latest runtime for your visual studio version. 
You can do so from here: [crystal runtimes for visual studio](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2017, you will need to have a more recent version of the Crystal SDK.

See:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Seems you need Support Pack 21 and higher. Try link below and see if it helps.

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_21.exe